# Given N integers, count the number of pairs of integers whose difference is K

Tags: php, arrays, time-complexity

I was given an array like this `array(1,5,3,4,2);`
Say `k=2`, I'm supposed to find out the count of pairs whose difference is 2. In this case it should return 3 because `5-3, 4-2, 3-1`

Here's what I have tried. It works fine I'm looping through the array twice `O(n^2)` complexity, I'm wondering if there is a better way to achieve this.

```
$arr = array(1,5,3,4,2); 
$k =2;
function find_pairs($arr, $k)
{
    $count = 0;
    for ($i=0 ; $i<= count($arr)-1 ; $i++)
    {
        for ($j=$i+1; $j <= count($arr)-1 ; $j++)
        {
            if ($arr[$i]-$arr[$j] == $k || $arr[$j]-$arr[$i]==$k)
            {
                $count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return $count;
}
echo find_pairs($arr, $k);
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you want all the possible combinations of difference 2  with array values right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ofcourse, There are many ways:

Using Sorting:

```
Sort the array arr
Take two pointers, l and r, both pointing to 1st element
Take the difference arr[r] – arr[l]
If value diff is K, increment count and move both pointers to next element
if value diff > k, move l to next element
if value diff < k, move r to next element
return count
```

one with complexity of O(n) is :

```
1) Initialize count as 0.
2) Insert all distinct elements of arr[] in a hash map.  While inserting, 
   ignore an element if already present in the hash map.
3) Do following for each element arr[i].
   a) Look for arr[i] + k in the hash map, if found then increment count.
   b) Look for arr[i] - k in the hash map, if found then increment count.
   c) Remove arr[i] from hash table.
```

Anyways you can refer to this [link](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-pairs-difference-equal-k/) for more info.

Comment: This approach is not O(n). Actually, I don't think O(n) is even possible in this scenario. Best that can be done is O(n logn). Searching for any element in hashmap takes O(log n).

Comment: A simple hashing technique to use values as index can be used to search an element in constant time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course. Below is something you can use:

- sort array (a, say and n elements)
- search (binary) for a[i]+k for all elements from index 0 through n-2. No. of successful hits is your answer.

This has O(n log n) complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. You may use unordered_set. Elaboration is given below :

```
1. Insert the all elements of array into unordered_set.
2. Initialize count=0
3. for loop i=0 to i=n where n is the length of array
         if arr[i]+k is found then increment count
4. Return count.
```

The complexity of above procedure is O(N).

Php code Snippet:

```
function find_pairs($a, $k) 
{
    $num = array_flip($a);
    $count = 0;
    foreach($num as $n => $_unused) 
    {
        if(isset($num[$n + $k])) 
        {
            $count++;
        }
    }
    return $count;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Given an integer n, count and return the number of zeros that are present in the given integer using recursion.

```
def count0(n):
    if n==0:
        return 0
    if n%10==0:
        return 1+count0(int(n/10))
    else:
        return count0(int(n/10))

n=int(input())
print(count0(n))
```

Comment: This does not answer OP question